# How can I calculate percentage change between a previous row from current row in the same column in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

this is the query I have but the percentage change column is wrong

```
select 
     year(ref_date), trade, trade_category, totalvalue, 
round(((totalvalue) - (LAG(totalvalue) OVER(ORDER BY year(ref_date))*100/ totalvalue)),0) percent_change 

from 
     data.services 
where 
    trade_category != "Commercial services, total" 
and 
    trade_category = "Financial services" 
group by 
     year(ref_date) 
order by 
      year(ref_date), totalvalue;
```

[below is the result but the calculation for percentage change is work][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoIcT.png

Comment: You're missing the window specification on the LAG: `LAG(total) OVER (ORDER BY datetime)` ... replace the datetime expression with whatever you use to order the rows.

Comment: I understand what you mean but this give me an error

Comment: Update/edit the question with more detail, like the exact SQL you executed and the exact error. Also note the version of MySQL you're using: `SELECT version();`  Window functions are new to MySQL, as of MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.2.2.

Comment: You also have a problem with `GROUP BY` use.  `type` and `total` are not functionally dependent on the `GROUP BY` terms.  Are you sure you want to `GROUP BY` or do you want to calculate over rows of the original table?  As part of your test case (in the question) you should add some data and show the exact result you wish to produce, given that specific test data.

Comment: @JonArmstrong my version is 10.5.5-MariaDB

Comment: Well, you only think your query is working because MariaDB has not yet implemented the `GROUP BY` and `functional dependence` logic of MySQL 5.7, so MariaDB doesn't inform you of your mistake.  That query should produce an error.  MariaDB is ignoring the mistake.  MySQL (which is the tag you used) with window functions would have the new logic and would produce an error, if configured properly.

Comment: okay...what query would I use to calculate the percentage change between two rows of the same column

Comment: Again, you haven't provided a requirement.  It's not clear you want `GROUP BY`.  It's not clear which `total` you want and which rows you're referring to.  A test case with expected results would be helpful.  Remember, `total` is not guaranteed to be one and only one value per `year_date, type_category` group.  A completely described test case would be helpful.

Comment: @JonArmstrong I have update the question and the query, I hope that make it clear for you. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The form of tghe window function must be held you can't add `/total` to it

```
LAG (column) OVER (PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col3)
```

Read mor abou window function in the [manua](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html)

```
select 
     year(year_date), type, type_category, total, 
round(((100.00 * total) - (LAG(total) OVER(ORDER BY year_date)/ total)),0) percent_change 

from 
     kev.trade 
where 
     type = "science" 
and 
     type_category = "data services" 
group by 
     year_date, type_category 
order by 
      year_date, total;
```

Comment: thanks your code works but the percentage calculation is formula is wrong. does this mean i cant use LAG() to calculate the percentage change

Comment: your window function, is not complete as mentioned usually you have an PARTITION BY, you really need to read the4 link provided all chapters. But now you have an working query and you can manipulate till the result fits